# Does any Python IDE let you run a selection of code like R does?

Tags: python, ide

I think this is a very useful feature for beginners. When I learned R, I would keep my notes for each lesson in one file and execute the lines that I wanted. Now I'm learning Python, and I have to save each new thing in a different file. Is there no IDE that can do what R does? I'm currently using PyCharm.

Comment: "Is there no IDE that does what R does"? You can call Python from the terminal just like you can call R from the terminal. Are you talking about R Studio or something?

Comment: What's wrong with commenting out unused code?

Comment: PyScripter allows you to select some code and press F7 to run it.

Comment: I get the feeling you're getting into some bad habits with this flow.  In general, you'd want to save the files and code you've done, and open a new file to avoid squashing/losing the work you've already done before.

Answer (score 7):

In PyCharm, select a code fragment you want to execute then choose "Execute selection in console" (Alt+Shift+E in my keymap).

Answer (score 2):

[PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) supports selective execution(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) along with loads of other features among which are Regular Expressions Tester, Unit Testing, Debugging(using watches) and all the other features an IDE must possess.

Answer (score 1):

[ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html) does a good job of this.  Good for learning, and code exploration.

Unfortunately, it's a bit of a pain to setup.  If you're just getting started you might want to consider installing the [pythonXY](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/Downloads) package of python, it includes ipython notebook and a bunch of other useful libraries in addition to the standard libraries.

Here's a good introduction (ipython notebook starts at about 1:15:45):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2G5YTlheCbw

Answer (score 0):

[Wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) can do this task for you.

Comment: Do you know what the hotkey is?

Comment: @d8aninja I haven't used Wing in years, so no, I don't know.